# How to deploy the Routerlicious fluid-server(fluid framework) using the Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, fluid-framework

Greetings for the day!

I want to deploy the open-source fluid server a.k.a `routerlicious` using the Kubernetes. Inside the fluid official repository
`https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework`

on the following path

https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/server/routerlicious/kubernetes

`routerlicious` is packaged as `Helm chart`.

My question is, Is it possible to deploy this helm chart to some other cloud than the Azure?

And is it possible to configure the base components on the local host?

I have been trying a lot in the past but I couldn't figure out a way.   I desperately need help on this.
I want to experiment with the routerlicious for some application ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, Is it possible to deploy this helm chart to some other cloud than the Azure?

The answer is yes. K8S is agnostic to any cloud provider, or any local K8S implementations like (`minikube`, `k3s`, `kind` etc).

> And is it possible to configure the base components on the local host?

Again, the answer is yes but you need to keep in mind that you might not be able to have all the resources, for example, you cannot have LB but you can simulate it with tools like [minikube tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/), [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/)

Comment: Thanks for reaching out codeWizard. what would you say about this ```kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret --docker-server=prague.azurecr.io --docker-username=prague --docker-password=/vM3i=D+K4+vj+pgha=cg=55OQLDWj3w --docker-email=kurtb@microsoft.com``` Should it work on any machine ?

Comment: I get issues on this